# SD Card Interface with Pic Mcu - Part_1

Tags: pic, microsd

I am trying to interface micro SD card with PIC MCU using SPI-mode of SD protocol.

Being a beginner, I tried to get the R1 response from the SD card by sending the command '0' through SPI ie.,

```
0x40
0x00
0x00
0x00
0x00
0x95
```

But I am not getting the response as `0x01` (in Idle mode)..

The source code is as follows (the PIC MCU I am using is [PIC32mx360f512l](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en532441))

```
/*********************************************************************
 *
 *                 PIC32 - SD card interface
 *
 *********************************************************************
 *
 * Dependencies:    p32xxxx.h
 *
 *
 * Processor:       PIC32
 *
 * Complier:        MPLAB C32
 *                  MPLAB IDE v8.0+
 * Company:         Microchip Technology Inc.
 *
 * Software License Agreement
 *
 *
 ********************************************************************/


#include <p32xxxx.h>
#include <plib.h>

// Config settings
// POSCMOD = HS, FNOSC = PRIPLL, FWDTEN = OFF
// PLLIDIV = DIV_2, PLLMUL = MUL_16
// PBDIV = 8 (default)
// Main clock = 8MHz /2 * 16    = 80MHz
// Peripheral clock = 80MHz /8  =  10MHz

// Configuration Bit settings
// SYSCLK = 80 MHz (8MHz Crystal/ FPLLIDIV * FPLLMUL / FPLLODIV)
// PBCLK = 10 MHz
// Primary Osc w/PLL (XT+,HS+,EC+PLL)
// WDT OFF
// Other options are don't care
//
#pragma config FPLLMUL = MUL_20, FPLLIDIV = DIV_2, FPLLODIV = DIV_1, FWDTEN = OFF
#pragma config POSCMOD = HS, FNOSC = PRIPLL, FPBDIV = DIV_8

#define SYS_FREQ            (40000000L)
void initialize();
void delay(double k);
void write_byte();


int delay_count,loop;
double d1,d2,d3;
int loop_var01 = 0;
int loop_var02 = 0;
int loop_var03 = 0;
int success_flag=0;
int i , j , k , l , m , n , o;
unsigned char  char_01,char_02 , char_03 , char_04 , char_05 , char_06 ,char_07, response_01;
char read_byte();
void toggle_clock();


int main(void)
{
    int delay;
    delay = 250;
    SYSTEMConfig(SYS_FREQ, SYS_CFG_WAIT_STATES | SYS_CFG_PCACHE);
    initialize();
    if(TRISDbits.TRISD2 == 1)       // if rd2 ie., DO is 1, check for flags

    while( 1)
    {
    }

}

void initialize()
{

// initialize the port pin directions
TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 0;
TRISDbits.TRISD1 = 0;
TRISDbits.TRISD2 = 1;
TRISDbits.TRISD3 = 0;

// initialize the SPI card to SPI mode
delay(10);
PORTDbits.RD3 = 1;
PORTDbits.RD1 = 1;


// do this a minimum of 74 times
for(loop_var01=0;loop_var01<80;loop_var01++)
{
 toggle_clock();
}
PORTDbits.RD1 = 0;

write_byte(0x44);
write_byte(0x00);
write_byte(0x00);
write_byte(0x00);
write_byte(0x00);
write_byte(0x95);


response_01 = read_byte();

if (response_01 == 0x01)
    success_flag=1;

else
    success_flag=0;  

}

//write byte ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

  void write_byte(char_02)
  {
    for(n=7;n>=0;n--)
    {
      if (char_02 & (1<<n))
         {PORTDbits.RD3 = 1;}
      else 
         {PORTDbits.RD3 = 0;}
      toggle_clock();
     } 

  }

//read byte +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

  char read_byte()
  {
    while(PORTDbits.RD2)   // read the DO input till the the bit becomes 0
    {  
     toggle_clock();
    }

    for (n=0;n<7;n++)
    { if (PORTDbits.RD2)
         { char_03 |=(1<<n); }
      else
         { char_03 &=~(1<<n); }
      toggle_clock();
    }
    return char_03;

  }

//toggle clock +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
void toggle_clock()
{
delay(100000);
PORTDbits.RD0 = 0;
delay(100000);
PORTDbits.RD0 = 1;
delay(100000);
}

//delay ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
void delay(double k)
{ 
  for(k=0;k<delay_count;k++)
  { for (l=0;l<1000;l++){}}
}
```

Please help me to figure out why I am getting junk or no response

Sub-Question:

How to pass the next command (say command24)?

I mean what is the hex value for command 24? I learnt that every command should begin with 01 followed by 'six bis' corresponding to the command number(in this case it is 24)??

What should be filled inside the quotes 0x"" for command 24??

how to pass arguments?? what is its hex value?? Is it 0x00 again or something else??

Comment: @Vicky Rao Could you put the code in the code tabs as its really confusing how it looks. I would change it but I don't want to end the content.

Comment: @Dean - Wrapping code in code tags, as you can see, puts vertical scroll bars on long code sections.  You don't have to worry about pushing content down.

Comment: @Daniel - Nice edit!

Comment: @reem, Thanks. But merits to @lacop who made the first edit.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem.. The DO line of the SD card never becomes high(which is usually high and turns low when card is giving response).. Please tell me why it is not getting high..

Comment: CMD0 is `0x40` and not `0x44`, see [Simplified Specs](http://www.sdcard.org/developers/tech/sdcard/pls/simplified_specs/) on sdcard.org

Comment: I am still working on that Sdcard thing.. There has been some improvement in my work,got command-response for reset,init, write, read and data-response for write.. Data-response for read is always 0xff(which is supposed to be 0xfe).. "Figuringggggg it out".. If the interface works properly, I will post all the changes I have made(hw and sw)

Comment: It sounds like it could be a problem with the hardware if you are getting no communication at all between the PIC and the SD card. Can you send us a schematic of how you have it wired up?

Answer (score 1):

You could try connecting a logic analyzer to the bus. This will allow you to double check your SPI bus timing and make sure that you are sending what you think you are sending from the PIC to the SD card.

If you don't have a logic analyzer there are many bus analyzers on the market for ~$100 that work very well for debugging serial protocols like SPI and I2C.
http://www.usbee.com/busbee.html

http://www.saleae.com/logic/